# PivotItem's header icon is invisible on secondary screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have a simple UWP application, where pivot item's headers are BitmapIcons. All works perfectly on my primary screen, but when app is launched on secondary screen, header icons are invisible.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
<Page
        x:Class="IconTest.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:IconTest"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                                Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..." />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                                Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="In condimentum nulla neque, eget accumsan diam malesuada tincidunt..." />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                                Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Fusce ac condimentum neque. In luctus suscipit ex sed tempor..." />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Page>
```

Does anybody have an idea, what's going on?
I'm using visual studio 2017 v. 15.4.3

**Update:**

I have two screens attached to my computer with extended layout. In windows the application will be launched on that screen, where it was previously closed.

Comment: What did you mean about "secondary screen"? Please provide the detailed reproducible steps.

Comment: I have two screens attached to my computer. If application is started on screen number 1, icons are visible. When starting app on screen number 2, icons are invisible.

Application will be launched on that screen, where it was previously closed.

Oh, and I have divided screen layout.

Comment: I mean that I have extended displays. I'm sorry for my poor english :/

Comment: What's your OS version and project's target version?

Comment: Target version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0 Build 14393), OS version: 1709